# Missing Records in the Middle - Logic App - SQL Connector - When an Item is Created

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I have a logic app, it skipped few records in the middle and never picked up. It happened twice over a span of 3 days. It didn't happen again for a week. Here's the configuration attached.

[image]

Comment: we have reproduced the same from our end and observed that every row is being recorded until there is no proper format of 'insert' command(i.e.. given the datatype of that column).

Comment: Thanks, we will analyze our insert query input data types.

Comment: Is your issue resolved?